# Why do I get a runtime error on online Jugde?

Tags: java, string

I'm getting a RunTime error while submitting my code on Online Judge.
The problem: Check if one `String` contains another `String` with words in between.
You get two strings in input, separated by a blank space. The code i have below works for all the sample input and outputs that they supply.

Sample Input:
sequence subsequence

person compression

VERDI vivaVittorioEmanueleReDiItalia

caseDoesMatter CaseDoesMatter

Sample output:
Yes

No

Yes

No

[Link to the problem](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1281)

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader instream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] s;
        int index = 0;

        while((s = instream.readLine().split(" ")) != null){
            index = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < s[1].length(); i++){
                if(s[0].charAt(index) == s[1].charAt(i))
                    index++;
                if(index == s[0].length())
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println(index == s[0].length() ? "Yes": "No");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was the while loop. I changed to instream.ready() instead and it worked like a charm! Thanks for the help guys!